# Is it possible to migrate questions of an account to another account?

Tags: discussion, accounts

Because my country forbids the usage of Google, I am having great difficulty logging with Google account. I have asked many questions with my Google account.

I want to register a new Stack Exchange account. I am wondering if there's a way to migrate those questions to my new account? Or is there a way to export all my previous questions?

Thanks for any advice. This is very important to me.

Comment: Why not just add another login to your existing account? Click the "my logins" link at the top of your profile, and you can add something else, even remove the Google one afterwards.

Comment: @animuson I just registered a LiveJournal account. I tried create a login with it, but SO says `We're sorry, we couldn't find the page you requested.`

Comment: As I tried, it seems I have to quit my current google account and re-login. And then add the LiveJournal login. It works now. Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you create an SE OpenID instead of some failure-prone third-party service ?

Comment: @AndréDaniel Because I didn't see the SE OpenID option in Add Login page.

Comment: @AndréDaniel It'll be great if I can add a new SE login with my Google login.

Comment: @smwikipedia you can [manually create an SE OpenID](https://openid.stackexchange.com/) and then add it to your account by proceeding as if it was a third-party provider and giving the OpenID URL when adding it to your logins.